# JS: Getting Different Values for Similar Functions

Tags: javascript

Below I have two code snippets with an identical object and function in both. So they should both return the same value.
The only difference I can see is the addition of brackets and an 'else' statement in the 'for loop' in the function in the bottom code snippet.

Why do the functions in each code snippet return different values instead of the same value? Thanks

```js
var employees = [{
  firstName: 'Ollie',
  lastName: 'Hepburn',
  role: 'Boss'
}, {
  firstName: 'Morty',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  role: 'Truck Driver'
}, {
  firstName: 'Peter',
  lastName: 'Ross',
  role: 'Warehouse Manager'
}, {
  firstName: 'Cal',
  lastName: 'Neil',
  role: 'Sales Assistant'
}, {
  firstName: 'Jesse',
  lastName: 'Saunders',
  role: 'Admin'
}, {
  firstName: 'Anna',
  lastName: 'Jones',
  role: 'Sales Assistant'
}, {
  firstName: 'Carmel',
  lastName: 'Hamm',
  role: 'Admin'
}, {
  firstName: 'Tori',
  lastName: 'Sparks',
  role: 'Sales Manager'
}, {
  firstName: 'Peter',
  lastName: 'Jones',
  role: 'Warehouse Picker'
}, {
  firstName: 'Mort',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  role: 'Warehouse Picker'
}, {
  firstName: 'Anna',
  lastName: 'Bell',
  role: 'Admin'
}, {
  firstName: 'Jewel',
  lastName: 'Bell',
  role: 'Receptionist'
}, {
  firstName: 'Colin',
  lastName: 'Brown',
  role: 'Trainee'
}];

function findEmployeesRole(name) {
  for(var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
    if(name === employees[i].firstName + " " + employees[i].lastName) return employees[i].role;
  return "Does not work here!";
}
                                      
                                      console.log(findEmployeesRole("Colin Brown"));
```

The function below the object in the below code snippet has the brackets in the for loop.

```js
var employees = [{
  firstName: 'Ollie',
  lastName: 'Hepburn',
  role: 'Boss'
}, {
  firstName: 'Morty',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  role: 'Truck Driver'
}, {
  firstName: 'Peter',
  lastName: 'Ross',
  role: 'Warehouse Manager'
}, {
  firstName: 'Cal',
  lastName: 'Neil',
  role: 'Sales Assistant'
}, {
  firstName: 'Jesse',
  lastName: 'Saunders',
  role: 'Admin'
}, {
  firstName: 'Anna',
  lastName: 'Jones',
  role: 'Sales Assistant'
}, {
  firstName: 'Carmel',
  lastName: 'Hamm',
  role: 'Admin'
}, {
  firstName: 'Tori',
  lastName: 'Sparks',
  role: 'Sales Manager'
}, {
  firstName: 'Peter',
  lastName: 'Jones',
  role: 'Warehouse Picker'
}, {
  firstName: 'Mort',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  role: 'Warehouse Picker'
}, {
  firstName: 'Anna',
  lastName: 'Bell',
  role: 'Admin'
}, {
  firstName: 'Jewel',
  lastName: 'Bell',
  role: 'Receptionist'
}, {
  firstName: 'Colin',
  lastName: 'Brown',
  role: 'Trainee'
}];

function findEmployeesRole(name) {
  for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++){
    if(name === employees[i].firstName + " " + employees[i].lastName){
      return employees[i].role;
    } else {
      return "Does not work here!";
    }
  }
}

console.log(findEmployeesRole("Colin Brown"));
```

Comment: it's actually obvious if you think about the loop

Comment: So cute that this actually happens to people in real life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second set of code, it will only ever be able to check the first item. Either, you have a match on the first item and you return the role, otherwise you return "Does not work here", there's no chance for the loop to continue.

In the first piece of code, the return statement is actually outside the loop, which means it will only return "Does not work here" until all items have been checked. With braces, it would look like this:

```
function findEmployeesRole(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        if (name === employees[i].firstName + " " + employees[i].lastName) {
            return employees[i].role;
        }
    }
    return "Does not work here!";
}
```

It's generally considered good practice to always use braces to prevent situations like this where it's not entirely clear at first glance what's happening.

Comment: I see it! oh my gosh, spent an hour and a half trying to see it. Knew it was something simple. You've been so helpful with your explanation thank you!